# How can I reduce the duplicated use of if and else

Tags: python

How can I use decorator or what else elegant way to avoid lots of `if else` logic in my functions

```
class DataModification():
    @classmethod
    def schedule(cls, df):
        if df.empty:
            return df
        else:
            df.rename(columns={'_id':'release_id'}, inplace=True)
            df.set_index("release_id", drop=True, inplace=True)
            df.rename(columns={'is_projection':'projections_available'}, inplace=True)
            df.rename(columns={'is_statement':'statement_available'}, inplace=True)
            return df.sort_index()

    @classmethod
    def function_b(cls, df):
        if df.empty:
            return df
        else:
            df.rename(columns={'_id':'release_id'}, inplace=True)
            df.set_index("release_id", drop=True, inplace=True)
            return df.sort_index()
```

Comment: Have you tried writing such a decorator? What happened?

Comment: You could just eliminate both else lines because when their preceeding if statement is true a return is executed and the else won't be executed.

Comment: `df.call_if_not_empty(DataModification.schedule)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods could be rewritten to something like this:

```
@classmethod
def function_b(cls, df):
    if df.empty:
        return df
    df.rename(columns={'_id':'release_id'}, inplace=True)
    df.set_index("release_id", drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df.sort_index()
```

Since the first return would make sure that the code in the `else` block doesn't run if the `if`s condition is `True`.

This is just two lines that you see everywhere in Python code - so I don't think a decorator is necessary. It just adds complexity and gives you one line less code for each function. If you are counting lines, you could also write:

```
if df.empty: return df
```

It's a bit less readable, in my opinion.

---

Try writing the decorator as an exercise. I think it should work like this:

```
class Foo:
    @return_empty
    def bar(self, df):
        print "Not empty: %s" % df

class Test(set):
    @property
    def empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

>>> f = Foo()    
>>> t = Test()   
>>> f.bar(t)
set()
>>> t.add(1)
>>> f.bar(t)
Not empty: Test([1])
```

**Spoiler**

> `def return_empty(f):
>      def _wrapper(self, df):
>          if df.empty:
>              return df
>          return f(self, df)
>      return _wrapper`

Comment: Thanks for the edit @jonrsharpe, I failed to make the code block inside the spoiler block.

Comment: It turned out to be trickier than I thought! And still looks wrong on the iOS app, though it worked on my desktop browser...

Comment: Whitespace seems to be removed in the Android app as well. I still like it this way. Maybe that's a bug in the app(s), not with your formatting?

Comment: I'll write it up on Meta later today, see if anyone else agrees it's broken!